# Busca por Faixa de CEP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Boa tarde, preciso buscar um cep dento da faixa de cep cadastrado no banco...

```
**banco de dados:**
cep_id | cidade | cep_de    | cep_ate
1      | jau    | 10000000  | 15000000



$cep = "15086210";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM ceps WHERE :a BETWEEN cep_de AND cep_ate");                                    
$stmt->bindParam(':a', $cep);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

if($result->cep_de == $cep):
 echo "ok";
else:
 echo "erro";
endif;
```

Se o cep estiver dentro da faixa de cep cadastrada ele dá um 'ok", se não tiver dentro da faixa ele retorna um "erro".

Como faço para me retornar o resultado?

Comment: `WHERE cep_de = :a BETWEEN cep_de AND cep_ate` essa mistura de `=` com `BETWEEN` não faz muito sentido para o que quer. Se quer um cep dentro de uma faixa basta `WHERE :a BETWEEN cep_de AND cep_ate` - Essas coisas geralmente se resolvem usando exemplos do próprio manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Comment: @Bacco Onde minha pergunta não ficou clara? Pode me ajudar?

Comment: Está clara, quem disse que não? Foi fechada por erro de digitação, não por falta de clareza. Conforme primeiro comentário (que já contém a solução) - trata-se de erro de sintaxe, até indiquei o manual com exemplos. Segue novamente a sintaxe correta do where, para evitar maus entendidos: `WHERE :a BETWEEN cep_de AND cep_ate`

Comment: @Bacco entendi... fiz conforme vc passou, mas não está retornando o resultado. Como faço isso?

Comment: Bom, tem mais problemas, tipo isso aqui no seu código `if($result->cep_de == $cep)` - seria bom tirar essas partes irrelevantes e simplesmente mostrar o resultado que veio. Testar retorno de DB com "if" geralmente não faz nenhum sentido

Comment: @Bacco mas eu preciso dar um retorno via ajax, se o cep que foi digitado esta dentro da area que é atendida.

Comment: Ai você está misturando um problema que não tem nada a ver com nossa conversa. Primeiro precisa aprender a fazer o básico do SQL, que é o 1o erro sério do seu post; quando isso funcionar (Sem PHP nem nada) aí você passa pra questão do PDO. Quando o PDO funcionar, aí vc pensa em AJAX, senão fica impossível.

Comment: Veja o SQL funcionando perfeitamente aqui: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/023946/1 - seu próximo passo lógico seria fazer isso funcionar no PDO com o `:a`. Como já disse, remova os ifs e simplesmente mostre o resultado na tela, fica mais fácil. `print_r( $result );`

Comment: @Bacco o PDO e todo o SQL está ok. fico agradecido. Agora nao sei como faço para ele me retornar o "ok e o "erro"

Comment: Se veio resultado é sempre OK, não? Erro seria se veio vazio.  Talvez fosse mehor retornar um array em vez de objeto, e simplesmente contar as quantidades retornadas (zero seria o erro talvez). Mas aí não tenho como dar mais sugestões pois depende de como você vai usar os valores.

Comment: @Bacco preciso que apos fazer a verificacao ele me retorne se está dentro da faixa que atendemos ou não. Não tem como fazer isso com "if"? como no exemplo que dei acima?

Comment: Bom, tenho que encerrar aqui por hoje pra fazer outras coisas, mas lembre-se que seus pontos já pemitem usar a sala de chat "Estouro de Pilha", acessível pelo menu do site. Essas horas é meio vazio, mas nos horários de expediente sempre tem gente. Lá é um espaço melhor para coisas que não cabem bem no formato pergunta objetiva × resposta objetiva

Comment: o between só retornará se está nas faixas do DB. Se quer uma específica precisa testar se o ID é atendido. Agora, se o DB só tem as faixas que vc atendem é o que eu falei antes - se vier algum resultado é sempre OK

Comment: @Bacco entao pego pelo id.... vou testar... vlw